# which of these would be a valid query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I have some confusion about aggregate functions and what's allowed in the select statement. So I have this little note:

```
Restrictions on aggregation: if any aggregation is used, then each element 
in the select list must be either aggregated or an attribute on the group by list
```

My confusion with the above is that: Does that mean that anything in the select statement that's an argument of the aggregate function have to be grouped? ie.

```
select max(attribute) from table group by attribute
```

I don't understand that restriction on aggregation.

So this leads to my question:

Here is my schema:  I don't know how to underline so i'll just state the keys

```
Student(sID, surName, firstName, campus, email, cgpa) key: sID
Course(dept, cNum, name, breadth)   key: dept, cNum
Offering(oID, dept, cNum, term, instructor)   key: oID
Took(sID, oID, grade)  key: sID, oID
```

I have an unfinished sql query:

```
select ________ from Offering, Took where Offering.oID = Took.oID group by dept
```

which of the following can go in the select clause and why is it allowed?:

```
sid,    count(sid),  grade,  avg(grade),  dept,  count(dept),  term,  min(term)
```

EDIT: wrote the wrong query. IT's the correct one now sorry.

Comment: @Strawberry is that for the new query? or the one you saw before?

Comment: could you provide data samples and expected result you want to get? that would help a lot

Comment: @Alex that would pretty much answer the question now wouldn't it? :p

Comment: Assuming only one column will fit, then none of the above. The correct answer is dept *plus* any (and/or all) of the aggregated columns.

Answer (score 0):

When using aggregations, any field in the `SELECT` clause that is not inside an aggregate function should be in `GROUP BY` too or you cannot use that field in the `SELECT`.

In your sample these fields have to be in `GROUP BY`: sid, grade, dept, term

Comment: Well, you *can*. MySQL forgives the abberation - but it's bad practice.